# Django choosen user permission is not showing in admin page

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I tried to extend default Django user in my project by using  **AbstractUser**. In Django admin i couldn't see choosen user permissions.

[image]

Here is my work

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class ExtendedUser(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

After that i add my extended user in **admin.py**

```
class ExtendedUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(ExtendedUser, ExtendedUserAdmin)
```

Also add AUTH_USER_MODEL in **settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = '_aaron_user.ExtendedUser'
```

Comment: delete your password from that image

Comment: password is not important. It is just for development purposes. Thanks @aws_apprentice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this problem by importing UserAdmin and register my ExtendedUser with this model in my **admin.py** file.

```
from.models import ExtendedUser
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(ExtendedUser, UserAdmin)
```

The result is choosen groups and choosen user permissions are now available.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those who use custom User model you need to add next code in **admin.py**:

```
filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
```

For example:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreationForm, CustomUserChangeForm
from .models import CustomUser


    class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
        search_fields = ('email',)
        list_display = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
        list_filter = ('email', 'is_staff', 'is_active',)
        filter_horizontal = ('groups', 'user_permissions',)
    
        class Meta:
            model = CustomUser
    
    admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

The line **filter_horizontal** is taken from original **django.contrib.auth.admin** class **UserAdmin**

After that 'Choosen groups' and 'Choosen user permissions' are available.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was missing `bootstrap` files from `static/admin|css|js`